# How to make div height to 100% of parent td

Tags: html, css, html-table

This is my current code:

```css
table{
    table-layout: fixed;
}
table tr td{
    height: 100%;
}
table tr td div{
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div>Test</div></td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see the red `div` doesn't take the 100% of the parent `td`. I can't set fix dimensions to the parents, as they should adjust automatically to the content.

How can I set the `div` height to be 100% like the parent `td` height?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```css
table{
    table-layout: fixed;
    height:100%;
}

table tr td div{
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    top:0;
}
```

```html
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div>Test</div></td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Add following style cases inside `table tr td div`. Your div height will be 100% like the parent td.**

```
table tr td div{
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;/* NEWLY ADDED */
    width: 100%;/* NEWLY ADDED */
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get it to work with that code. Please provide a full example like in the original question.

Answer (score -1):

**Please use the below code.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <style>
  table{
    table-layout: fixed;
  }
  table tr td{
      height: 100%;
  }
  table tr td div{
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;/* NEWLY ADDED */
    width: 100%;/* NEWLY ADDED */
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div>Test</div></td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Doesn't work in the latest Firefox Developer edition.